# Releasing attributes from Model

Tags: spring-mvc, attributes, model, request, try-catch

I am setting couple attributes to a model of Spring Model

```
 myModel.setValue1
 myModel.setValue2  //Now setting this to request
 request.setAttribute("All_Values", myModel)
```

Making a service call under try catch block. If exception received, I want to release the `Value2` from my model and set only `Value1` to my request and make a service call again.

```
 try{
 service call
 ...
 }catch(Exception e){
 myModel.release Value2 and have only Value1
 request.setAttribute("All_values", myModel) //This has only Value1
 service call again
 }
```

This is just an example if I could release couple of values if Exception received. **I have many values in my model and not just two**, so setting attributes individually to the request would be tedious.

Could this be done?

Comment: Why do you need to call `request.setAttribute()`?

Comment: @axtavt:I am sending the request along with other parameters to the service. Also the request is used to get portlet session, and some other stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should first do the controller logic and set the model attributes at the end of the controller method, after all the exception catching etc.

You can store the model attributes in a Map, where you can remove them if needed, and just before the return of the controller do:

```
model.addAllAttributes(attributesMap);
```